# Scenario is Transpose rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with two columns id and value where id integer datatype and value is decimal datatype

[image]

Output should be like that:

```
 1,13.0264757,77.6361745
 2,13.0276974,77.6327644
```

I use pivot operator but it is not working properly. Below query is my workout

```
select 1, 2, 3
from (
    select id, value
    from sampletest
) as srctable
pivot
(
    sum(value)
    for id in ([1],[2],[3])
) as pivttabl
```

Comment: you need to order your columns. Do you have any other column in table which can ensure ordering? Eg your output row can also be `2,13.0264757,77.6361745`

Comment: Why you think that first 1,2,3 shoud be grouped in one row? Is there anything common between 1,2,3 ?

Comment: No, those two are the only columns available for the table...@Dhruv Joshi

Comment: output is like that below                                                           1,13.0264757,77.6361745
 2,13.0276974,77.6327644   @DhruvJoshi

Comment: @AbdulMalik *"No, those two are the only columns available for the table"* that is literally not possible... You can not rely on the visible sort order of your table. Well, you will be able to write some code, which *seems* to return the wanted result. But with larger sets this is nothing else then random...

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can get values onto the rows using conditional aggregation.  For instance, for two rows:

```
select min(case when column_id = 1 then value end),
       min(case when column_id = 2 then value end),
       min(case when column_id = 3 then value end)      
from t
union all
select max(case when column_id = 1 then value end),
       max(case when column_id = 2 then value end),
       max(case when column_id = 3 then value end) ;
```

Note:  This is *not* the results that you specify in your question.

If you have an ordering column, you can express what you want as:

```
select min(case when column_id = 1 then value end),
       min(case when column_id = 2 then value end),
       min(case when column_id = 3 then value end)      
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column_id order by <ordering column>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

If you don't have an ordering column of some sort, then you cannot *reliably* do what you want.  Instead, you should fix your data model so the data has the information you need.  This is usually handled by having an `identity` column; such a column is ordered by the "insert-order" of the rows into the table.